# Different behaviour of div hover style in dynamic and static HTML

Tags: php, css, html, styles, hover

This question concerns a difference in CSS behaviour between a a page of static html using the same HTML and styles as a page generated dynamically using PHP.

In the static page the hover effect is applied by the following styles defined in a separate style sheet:

```
div.selectable_class { background-color:white}
div.selectable_class:hover { background-color:blue }
```

The static HTML fragment is as follows:

```
<div class="selectable_class" onclick="event handler here">
    <div class="ano_class">
        <!-- Contents-->
    </div>
</div>
```

When I load the static page using this code the hover effect works as expected and the colour changes from white to blue and back to white.

I then used the same style sheet and generated the HTML dynamically using PHP and noticed that the hover effect was been lost but the change of colour is triggered by clicking on the div.

To confirm that I was generating the dynamic HTML correctly I did a View Source and copied the generated HTML into a separate file and then loaded that in.

Magically, the hover effect worked correctly in that version!

I have looked elsewhere on this site and saw mention of the document type having an effect. In both cases my document type is specified as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```

For your information I am using Safari version 5.1.2.

If anyone can shed light on this behaviour I would be very grateful.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Web browser knows next no nothing about what happens on the server, i.e. it's all the same if it's static HTML or dynamically generated HTML. You should look further for the differences.

Comment: Any chance you could show us an example?

Comment: Not sure what other differences to look for given the code should be identical having been copied from the dynamic page and and pasted into the static page without any edits.

Comment: I can't demonstrate the PHP version I am afraid but I should be able to create a cutdown version of the static page with the same behaviour. I'll post it here but it may take a while.

Comment: Another idea: the generated version also includes some JavaScript code which overrides the behaviour.

Comment: I came back to the code this morning having left it alone for the weekend to find that it is now running perfectly for me too on Safari. I haven't added this as an answer yet as I can only guess that this may be related to some sort of caching/timing issue and that I had restarted my browser in between. I wonder whether a previous javascript load was overriding the behaviour (as per suggestion above)  since the offending code had the javascript removed.

Answer (score 1):

PHP runs on the server and has no knowledge or effect on how the web browser displays the resulting HTML, CSS.  If there is a difference then that means the HTML/CSS you are generating with PHP is not the same as the HTML/CSS contained in the static page.

Comment: As I explained above perhaps it is a caching issue of Javascript loaded in a previous run that doesn't show itself in the generated source code for that page?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily an answer to your question, but do keep in mind that early versions of IE don't understand :hover on an element that is NOT a link. I'm not sure in which version this stopped being true off the top of my head.

If you're looking for a cross-browser solution, then, you might have to resort to a javascript function, like jQuery's [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/). That might also be a way to solve your current problem.

Comment: Interestingly I provided a full copy of the code exhibiting this problem to a friend who is running IE and it worked perfectly for him.

Comment: I will certainly look at using the hover approach in jquery as I am using that library elsewhere to good effect.

Comment: After actually taking the time to look up my answer, I think it was just up to IE6. IE7 and later should respect :hover on all elements. If IE6 isn't an issue for you, you don't need to worry about it then.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. Yes I am sure that is right. I can't reproduce the problem now - that's sort of good! Will be keeping an eye on this though and the next time it happens try emptying the cache as that seems to be the most likely explanation so far - though it is still stretching things:-O